# extension doesn't work properly for c# in vsc

Tags: c#, .net, omnisharp

I've got a problem with C# in Visual Studio Code.

Support, debug and intellisense for c# is not working on new and old project
I search for this problem and found nothing, idk what I should do...
before i reinstalled my pc this was working

[image: intellisense doens't work]

[image: omnisharp error]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the C# extension for VS Code
[from extensions store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G7p3.png)

Comment: I have that's why I'am asking